# How to convert different values from map[string]interface{} to type string

Tags: go, types, type-assertion

I have a map with different types in interface{} and I need to convert them all to string type. Type assertion is not enough.

```
package main

func main() {
    map1 := map[string]interface{}{"str1": "string one", "int1": 123, "float1": 0.123}

    var slc []string
    for _, j := range map1 {
        slc = append(slc, j.(string)) // panic: interface conversion: interface {} is int, not string
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: You need a [type switch, covered in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) and [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).

Comment: An alternative that'll work for at least primitive (ie. non-struct) types is to append `fmt.Sprintf("%v", j)`.  This will convert them all to string via their default print format.  If you want type-specific conversion styles, use a typeswitch as @Adrian suggested.

Comment: Actually, I need to create POST request with properties from that map. So i need to get string type to create a request with that parameters. I think, fmt.Sprintf("%v", j) will works for me.

Comment: Better approach will be that to use type switch to check the value using type assertion and then convert everything to string.

Comment: I would highly suggest to change your map to `map[string]fmt.Stringer` if that is the purpose you have in mind. You can then just `range` the map and call `String()` on each element. I do realise that the demo values you have added do not all implement the Stringer interface but maybe that is easier to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Adrian and @Kaedys comments point to the correct answer. Developing it a bit more you could do something as:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    map1 := map[string]interface{}{"str1": "string one", "int1": 123, "float1": 0.123}

    var slc []string
    for _, j := range map1 {
        switch v := j.(type) {
        case string:
            slc = append(slc, v)
        case fmt.Stringer:
            slc = append(slc, v.String())
        default:
            slc = append(slc, fmt.Sprintf("%v", v))
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(slc)
}
```

This answer will work for strings, any type that implements the [`fmt.Stringer` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer), and will default to `fmt.Sprintf("%v", ...)`.